# Eliminar repetidos en un array de C

Tags: array, c

Estoy generando números de forma manual (`scanf()`) en un array, y no comprendo como podría hacer que al momento de introducir un numero repetido, el programa me avise y pueda sobrescribir ese numero. Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
void generarCartonManual (int m[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{

int i,k;

    for (i=0; i<RENGLON; i++){ //Renglones 3
        for (k=0; k<COLUMNA; k++){ //columnas 5
                printf("Renglon %d columna %d -> ",i,k);
             scanf("%d",&m[i][k]); //Guarda cada numero introducido por el usuario en la variable m.
                if (m[i][k]>90 || m[i][k]<0 ){
            printf("El numero introducido es mayor a 90 o menor a 0, introduzca nuevamente el numero.\n ");
            printf("Reescribe el numero ---> ");
            scanf("%d",&m[i][k]);
             }
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<RENGLON+1; i++){
        for (k=0; k<COLUMNA-1; k++){
            if(m[i]==m[k]){
                printf("Numero repetido\n");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Edito: No me queda del todo claro lo que van comentando, pero basicamente hice una estructura `do-while` y va quedando así la función, la cual todavía no funciona, pero creo que estoy encaminándome mejor:

```
void generarCartonManual (int m[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{

int i,k,numRepetidos=1;

    for (i=0; i<RENGLON; i++){ //Renglones 3
        for (k=0; k<COLUMNA; k++){ //columnas 5
                printf("Renglon %d columna %d -> ",i,k);
             scanf("%d",&m[i][k]); //Guarda cada numero introducido por el usuario en la variable m.
                if (m[i][k]>90 || m[i][k]<0 ){
            printf("El numero introducido es mayor a 90 o menor a 0, introduzca nuevamente el numero.\n ");
            printf("Reescribe el numero ---> ");
            scanf("%d",&m[i][k]);

            do {

            if(m[i]==m[k]){
                printf("Numero repetido\n");
            } else {
                numRepetidos==0;
            }

}
while (numRepetidos!=0);

             }
        }
    }
```

Edit 2: Logre concatenar la parte que me pasaron por el chat con algunas modificaciones el codigo va quedando bien, el tema es que el if que cumple la funcion de analizar el array para ver si el numero es mayor a 90 y menor a 0 no funciona siempre.

[image: Edit 2]

En que parte del codigo deberia poner el if, ya lo movi para todas partes pero no me queda bien el codigo, pasa siempre lo mismo.

Edit 3: A veces me dice que hay repetidos cuando no los hay
[image: e]

Esta es la funcion completa:

void generarCartonManual (int m[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{

```
int i,k,numRepetidos=1;

for (i=0; i<RENGLON; i++)  //Renglones 3
{
    for (k=0; k<COLUMNA; k++)  //columnas 5
    {
        printf("Renglon %d columna %d -> ",i,k);
        scanf("%d",&m[i][k]); //Guarda cada numero introducido por el usuario en la variable m.

        int repetido,y,x;
        do
        {
            int numero;
            printf("Renglon %d columna %d -> ",i,k);
            scanf("%d",&numero);

            repetido = 0;
            for (x=0; x<RENGLON && repetido == 0; x++)
            {
                for (y=0; y<COLUMNA && repetido == 0; y++)
                {
                    repetido = (m[x][y] == numero);
                    if (m[i][k]>90 || m[i][k]<0 )
                    {
                        printf("El numero introducido es mayor a 90 o menor a 0, introduzca nuevamente el numero.\n ");
                        printf("Reescribe el numero ---> ");
                        scanf("%d",&m[i][k]);
                    }
                }
            }

            if( repetido )
                printf("Numero repetido\n");
            else
                m[i][k] = numero; // El número no está repetido, lo guardamos en la matriz

        }
        while( repetido );

    }
}
```

Comment: Tal vez un `do {} while();`

Comment: cada vez que ingresas un numero tenes que volver a revisar todos los numero ya ingresados para ver si no se repite...

Comment: Estructura un codigo para satisfacer las necesidades por escala.

0.bucles for para moverte por la array.
1- ingresa el nuevo valor
2-inicia un bucle do while 
    2.1+ comprueva si el valor es repetido con los bucles for
    2.2+ abre un condicional que te avise de que es repetido
        2.2.1-> Si es repetido añadir nuevo valor
    2.3+ si no esta repetido canvia el valor de while para salir i seguir con el siguiente numero.

Comment: No entendi que es lo que queres decir @Ema

Comment: y dinde, luego de pedir el numero, recorres de vuelta los numeros ya ingresados?

Comment: Tengo que hacer otro fuera del if? No comprendo

Comment: @HatoriHanso revisa mi respuesta ;)

Comment: En los comentarios no permite escrivir salto de lineas. Prueba de copiar mi comentario y estructurarlo como si fuera un esquema. Alomejor asi lo entenderas mejor.

Answer (score 2):

```
do {
    if(m[i]==m[k]){
        printf("Numero repetido\n");
    } else {
        numRepetidos==0;
    }
} while (numRepetidos!=0);
```

El problema de este bucle es que va a hacer que tu aplicación deje de responder en el momento en el que añadas un número repetido. ¿Por qué? Básicamente porque el bucle comprueba una condición que **nunca** modifica:

- Fíjate que `numRepetidos==0` es **una comparación**, no una asignación
- Los valores de `i` y `k` no cambian nunca, **siempre** comprobarás la misma pareja de números
- `m` es un array, luego necesita dos índices y tu le estás facilitando únicamente uno

Para comprobar si un número está repetido tienes que comprobar el número contra todos los anteriores, es decir, necesitas recorrer de nuevo el array que estás rellenando:

```
int repetido;
do
{
    int numero;
    printf("Renglon %d columna %d -> ",i,k);
    scanf("%d",&numero); 

    repetido = 0;
    for (x=0; x<RENGLON && repetido == 0; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<COLUMNA && repetido == 0; y++)
        {
           repetido = (m[x][y] == numero);
        }
    }

    if( repetido )
      printf("Numero repetido\n");
    else
     m[i][k] = numero; // El número no está repetido, lo guardamos en la matriz

} while( repetido );
```

Para que este algoritmo funcione es necesario que se inicializen todos los valores de `m` a un valor que no se considere válido, por ejemplo `-1`

Comment: Como que los valores [i][k] no cambian nunca si estan dentro de un for

Comment: @HatoriHanso si, pero el while está dentro del for, luego para ejecutar una segunda iteración del for es necesario que la ejecución abandone el while... cosa que no hará porque el while no modifica dichos índices

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchisimas gracias, estoy analizando el codigo para entender bien que hiciste, nunca me explicaron como usar el for de esa manera, muchisimas gracias, ahora el problema esta en que puedo poner numeros mayores a 90 pero eso se solucionarlo, mil gracias!

Comment: Que vendria a ser while ( repetido ) ? Que condicion seria exactamente la que tiene que suceder?

Comment: @HatoriHanso no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: Editare el post

Comment: estoy teniendo tres problemas, los acomodare en base a la importancia:
1- Tengo que introducir mas de 15 numeros cuando la tabla tiene que ser de 15. 2- Me dice que hay repetidos cuando no los hay 3- No se donde acomodar el if que me scanea los numeros mayores a 90 y menores a 0.

Comment: Creo que el problema radica en que hay dos scanf en diferentes for. Pero no sabria como acomodar de forma correcta el codigo, pegare la funcion completa

Comment: @HatoriHanso mejor crea una pregunta nueva y revierte los cambios que has hecho

Comment: Listo, ya he creado el post nuevo y estoy logrando revertir los errores poco a poco. Pero sigo teniendo la misma duda de antes. Que significa while (repetido) y if (repetido). Nunca utilice **condiciones** de esa forma. Podrias explicarme porfavor en que caso repetido entraria al if o saldria del while?

Comment: Me surgio otra duda, Como haces para guardar muchos numeros y posiciones en una variable normal. Es decir. Como guardas tantos numeros en una variable como es "numero" sin necesidad de darle [] []. El codigo me funciona de forma perfecta pero no entiendo estos metodos que utilizas