# Problemas con array en C

Tags: array, c, punteros

estoy trabajando con una función que hace horas me esta comiendo la cabeza y recurro acá a ver si pueden darme una mano.
Los pongo en contexto. Tengo que generar de forma manual un cartón con 15 números (3 lineas y 5 números en cada linea (3x5=15)). Y estos números no se pueden repetir ni superar el 90 ni ser inferior a 0.
Mi progreso es el siguiente:

```
void generarCartonManual (int m[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{

    int i,k,numRepetidos=1;

    for (i=0; i<RENGLON; i++)  //Renglones 3
    {
        for (k=0; k<COLUMNA; k++)  //columnas 5
        {


            int repetido,y,x;
            do
            {
                int numero;
                printf("Renglon %d columna %d AAA -> ",i,k);
                scanf("%d",&numero);

                repetido = 0;
                for (x=0; x<RENGLON && repetido == 0; x++)
                {
                    for (y=0; y<COLUMNA && repetido == 0; y++)
                    {
                        repetido = (m[x][y] == numero);
                       /* if (m[i][k]>90 || m[i][k]<0 )
                        {
                            printf("El numero introducido es mayor a 90 o menor a 0, introduzca nuevamente el numero.\n ");
                            printf("Reescribe el numero ---> ");
                            scanf("%d",&m[i][k]);
                        }*/
                    }
                }

                if( repetido )
                    printf("Numero repetido\n");
                else
                    m[i][k] = numero; // El número no está repetido, lo guardamos en la matriz

            }
            while( repetido );

        }
    }

}
```

Problemas: Hay veces que me dice que un numero es repetido cuando **no es repetido.** Y también no me marca siempre que un numero es mayor a 90 o inferior a 1, solo en *x* momentos que aun no llego a comprender. Toda ayuda es bienvenida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hay veces que me dice que un numero es repetido cuando no es repetido

Eso es porque no me hiciste caso en el [hilo original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/383201/463) y no has inicializado los cartones con un número que sea de por sí inválido... como por ejemplo el -1

Si el programa solo se va a ejecutar una vez es algo que puedes hacer de forma trivial al declarar el array

```
int carton[RENGLON][COLUMNA] = { -1 };
```

O si no puedes optar por la forma genérica, que consiste en recorrer todo el array y asignar valores de forma manual:

```
for (int x=0; x<RENGLON && repetido == 0; x++)
{
    for (int y=0; y<COLUMNA && repetido == 0; y++)
    {
        m[x][y] = -1;
    }
}
```

> Y estos números no se pueden repetir ni superar el 90 ni ser inferior a 0

Estás metiendo código sin tener para nada claro dónde debería ir

- El detector de duplicados debe recorrer toda la matriz porque comprueba un valor con todos los que haya en la matriz
- El detector de rango solo debe validar el valor introducido por el usuario, luego **no necesita bucles**

Son dos algoritmos independientes con requisitos distintos y, por tanto, no deberían mezclarse.

```
int validoEnRango = 1;
int repetido = 0;

do
{
    if (numero>90 || numero<0 )
    {
        validoEnRango = 0;
        printf("El numero introducido es mayor a 90 o menor a 0, introduzca nuevamente el numero.\n ");
        printf("Reescribe el numero ---> ");
        scanf("%d",&m[i][k]);
    }
    else
    {
        repetido = 0;
        for (int x=0; x<RENGLON && repetido == 0; x++)
        {
            for (int y=0; y<COLUMNA && repetido == 0; y++)
            {
                repetido = (m[x][y] == numero);
            }
        }
    
        if( repetido )
            printf("Numero repetido\n");
        else
            m[i][k] = numero; // El número no está repetido, lo guardamos en la matriz
    
    }
} while( !validoEnRango || repetido );
```

E incluso sería factible moverlos a funciones independientes para añadir modularidad al código:

```
int estaDuplicado(int numero, int carton[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{
    int repetido = 0;
    for (int x=0; x<RENGLON && repetido == 0; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<COLUMNA && repetido == 0; y++)
        {
            repetido = (carton[x][y] == numero);
        }
    }

    return repetido;
}

int numeroEnRango(int numero)
{
    return numero >= 0 && numero <= 90;
}

// ...

int numero;
printf("Renglon %d columna %d AAA -> ",i,k);

int valido = 1;
do
{
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    
    int valido = numeroEnRango(numero);
    if( !valido )
    {
        printf("El numero introducido es mayor a 90 o menor a 0, introduzca nuevamente el numero.\n ");
        printf("Reescribe el numero ---> ");
    }
    else
    {
        valido = !estaDuplicado(numero, m);
    
        if( !valido )
            printf("Numero repetido\n");
    }
} while( !valido );

m[i][k] = numero; // El número es válido, lo guardamos en la matriz
```

Por cierto, nota que un Array de Tamaño Fijo tal que

```
int matriz[5][10];
```

Tiene dos características principales:

- se declara en la pila del programa
- se almacena en memoria de forma secuencial

Es decir

```
int matriz[2][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
```

quedaría en memoria así:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 <-- posiciones de memoria
 1  2  3  4  X  X
 ^           ^ 
 matriz      memoria de otra variable
```

Es decir, es perfectamente posible linealizar el array para simplificar las iteraciones:

```
// Esto
for (int x=0; x<RENGLON && repetido == 0; x++)
{
    for (int y=0; y<COLUMNA && repetido == 0; y++)
    {
        m[x][y] = -1;
    }
}

// Se reduce a
for( int x=0; x<RENGLON*COLUMNA; x++ )
{
    *((int*)m + x) = -1;
}

// O, aplicando aritmética de punteros
for( int * ptr = (int*)m; ptr != (int*)m + (RENGLON * COLUMNA); ++ptr )
{
    *ptr = -1;
}

// También podríamos escribir el bucle asi
for( int * ptr = &m[0][0]; ptr != &m[0][0] + (RENGLON * COLUMNA); ++ptr )
{
    *ptr = -1;
}

// O así
for( int * ptr = *m; ptr != *m + (RENGLON * COLUMNA); ++ptr )
{
    *ptr = -1;
}
```

Juntando todos estos conceptos el código podría quedar así:

```
void inicializarCarton(int carton[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{
    for( int * ptr = *carton, *end = *carton + (RENGLON * COLUMNA); ptr != end; ++ptr )
    {
        *ptr = -1;
    }
}

int estaDuplicado(int numero, int carton[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{
    int repetido = 0;
    for( int * ptr = *carton, *end = *carton + (RENGLON * COLUMNA); ptr != end && !repetido; ++ptr )
    {
        repetido = (*ptr == numero);
    }

    return repetido;
}

int numeroEnRango(int numero)
{
    return numero >= 0 && numero <= 90;
}


void generarCartonManual (int m[RENGLON][COLUMNA])
{
    inicializarCarton(m);

    for (int i=0; i<RENGLON; i++)  //Renglones 3
    {
        for (int k=0; k<COLUMNA; k++)  //columnas 5
        {
            int numero;
            printf("Renglon %d columna %d AAA -> ",i,k);
            
            int valido = 1;
            do
            {
                scanf("%d",&numero);
                    
                valido = numeroEnRango(numero);
                if( !valido )
                {
                    printf("El numero introducido es mayor a 90 o menor a 0, introduzca nuevamente el numero.\n ");
                    printf("Reescribe el numero ---> ");
                }
                else
                {
                    valido = !estaDuplicado(numero, m);
                    
                    if( !valido )
                       printf("Numero repetido\n");
                }
            } while( !valido );
            
            m[i][k] = numero; // El número es válido, lo guardamos en la matriz
        }
    }
}

Puedes verlo funcionando [aquí][2]
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu esfuerzo, pero sobrepasa demasiado mis conocimientos. Sigo sin entender porque en los while usas "while(repetidos)" no entiendo bien que condicion es la que usas, sigo hablando del post anterior. Y he intentado usar estos codigos que me pasaste pero tampoco me funcionan, muchas gracias

Comment: Disculpa, en alguna edición metí la pata y puse lo que comentas de dos bucles while... ya está corregido

Comment: Cuando utilizo el primer codigo que pasas, lo unico que hace por consola es mostrarme "Esta repetido" de forma infinita, sin introducir ningun numero